# Creating a matrix from the determinants of submatices of a given square matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm trying to create a Mathematica algorithm creates a matrix `f` when given a $n \times n$ square matrix `L`

1. If `i = j`, then `f[[i, i]] = 0`
2. If `i != j`, then `f[[i, j]] = d[L, {i, j}] /d[L, {i, i}]`

where `d[L, {i, j}]` is the determinant of `s[L, {i, j}]`, and `s[L, {i, j}]` is the sub-matrix of `L` which omits all elements of `L` that have a row index or a column index that appears in the list `{i, j}`, where `1 <=  i <= n` and `1 <=  j <= n`.

Note that when `i != j`. `s[L, {i, j}]` has dimensions `{n - 2, n - 2}`, because it omits two distinct indices, while `s[L, {i, i}]` has dimensions `{n - 1, n - 1}` because it omits only one.

My problem is that I'm trying to use `Drop` to delete rows and columns, but I get this error when `L` is a 4 x 4 matrix.

> Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions 4 through 4 in {{3,-1,-1},{-1,3,-1},{-1,-1,3}}.

My code is:

```
n = Dimensions[L][[1]]
f = 
  Table[
    If[i != j,
      Det[Drop[Drop[L, {i}, {i}], {j}, {j}]]/Det[Drop[L, {i}, {i}]], 
      f[[i, j]] = 0], 
    {i, n}, {j, n}]
```

I tried to change `j` to `j-1,` but doing so changes the concept of my problem and generates an incorrect matrix `f`.

Maybe my logic is not good. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This looks an edit to a question you asked previously: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148285

Comment: Yeah, sure, but after many changes I think my problem in the logic, not the code.

Comment: Then it would a good idea for you to delete the previous question,

Comment: Deleted, could you please help me ?

Comment: Note that if `Det[i, j]` is the determinant of `L` with row `i` and column`j` deleted, then it is obvious that `Det[i, i]` is the determinant of `L` with row `i` and column `i `deleted. There is not need to define this special case separately.

Comment: Mr Goldberg, I'm trying to edit my post because I'm not talking about row `i` and column `j` deleted but instead of it is: line (or row) `i` with respectively column `i` deleted and the same to `j`. It's like `i` is a element position where there are i-column and i-row.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from Luis's code, and from his question (before it was edited), that he wants to divide the determinant of a $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ matrix by the determinant of a $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. My answer is the only one that does this. Luis, could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, Carl Woll!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A related Mathematica function is [`Minors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors), but that does more work than you need. So, here is a more custom version:

```
minor[L_, {i_, j_}] := With[{x = Delete[Range @ Length @ L, {{i}, {j}}]},
    Det @ L[[x, x]]
]
```

By happenstance, this version works when $i=j$ as well. For example, suppose:

```
SeedRandom[1];
L = RandomInteger[20, {4, 4}]
L //TeXForm
```

> {{5, 0, 7, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 0}, {16, 14, 3, 8}, {19, 5, 18, 16}}
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  5 & 0 & 7 & 0 \\
>  2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
>  16 & 14 & 3 & 8 \\
>  19 & 5 & 18 & 16 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Then, we can answer your question with:

```
n = Length @ L;
Table[If[i==j, 0, minor[L, {i, j}]/minor[L, {i, i}]], {i, n}, {j, n}]
% //TeXForm
```

> {{0, 1/3, -(1/6), -(1/32)}, {12/151, 0, -(10/151), 97/1208}, {1/5, 1/3, 0, 1/
>     16}, {-(9/95), 97/95, -(3/19), 0}}
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{32} \\
>  \frac{12}{151} & 0 & -\frac{10}{151} & \frac{97}{1208} \\
>  \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{16} \\
>  -\frac{9}{95} & \frac{97}{95} & -\frac{3}{19} & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thank you so much, Carl !!! It was exactly this what I was looking for ! I don't have enough reputation to vote, but I need to confirm that this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @LuísEduardo But you said you wanted to delete row i and column j, not row i and j and column i and j.

Comment: @LuísEduardo. Even if can't up-vote, you can show your approval by accepting this answer. You do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: @Alan my post was edited by Mr Goldberg several times who maybe doesn't  understand what I was looking for... But thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 3):

Is this the function you're after?

```
f = Function[{m, ij}, With[{i = First@ij, j = Last@ij},
  If[i == j, 0,Det[Drop[m, {i}, {j}]]/Det[Drop[m, {i}, {i}]]]]
]
```

If so, you can just

```
MapIndexed[f[L, #2] &, L, {2}]
```

**Edit:**

Given the edits to the question, you need to make a small change to the function:

```
f = Function[{m, ij}, 
  With[{i = First@ij, j = Last@ij, mn = Min@ij, mx = Max@ij},
   If[i == j, 0,
    Det[Drop[Drop[m, {mx}, {mx}], {mn}, {mn}]]/Det[Drop[m, {i}, {i}]]]
   ]]
```

Comment: I don't understand this function. It didn't work! The output was just {1,1,1,1} to my 4x4 L matrix.

Comment: @LuísEduardo Sorry for the typo.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but it was not exactly this what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f, f1, f2]
f[L_] := Divide @@ (First[Extract[L, {{#, #}}, Det]] & /@ 
         (Complement[Range@Length@L, #] & /@ {{##}, {#}})) &

f1[L_] := Table[If[i == j, 0, f[L][i, j]], {i, Length@L}, {j, Length@L}]

f2[L_] := Array[f[L], {#, #}] - IdentityMatrix[#] & @ Length[L]



Row[MatrixForm /@ {L, f1 @ L, f2 @ L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very didactic, but it was similar to Alan, it's not exactly what I was looking for, because the solution will be different what I expected.

Comment: @Luis, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the now corrected definition of `f` in the question, which in turn is based on Carl Woll's insights.

```
d[mat_, all_, {i_, j_}] :=
  With[{indices = Delete[all, {{i}, {j}}]}, Det @ mat[[indices, indices]]]
f[m_?SquareMatrixQ] :=
   Module[{indices, subdets},
     indices = Range @ Length @ m;
     subdets = Array[d[m, indices, {##}] &, Dimensions[m]];
     ReplacePart[subdets/Diagonal[subdets], {i_, i_} -> 0]]
```

I think this code is a little more efficient than Carl's.

Here are some test cases.

```
f @ Array[a, {3, 3}]
```

[image: mat_1]

```
f @ {{5, 0, 7, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 0}, {16, 14, 3, 8}, {19, 5, 18, 16}}
```

[image: mat_2]