# Calculating Minors of a 3x3 matrix not giving correct output

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

The function Minors[] does not return what its suposse to.
Example:

```
mat = {{a, b, c}, {l, m, n}, {x, y, z}}
mat // MatrixForm
Minors[mat] // MatrixForm
```

The output for minors is :

```
{{-b l + a m, -c l + a n, -c m + b n}, {-b x + a y, -c x + a z, -c y +
    b z}, {-m x + l y, -n x + l z, -n y + m z}}
```

It calculates all the minors but places them in wrong possitions. Minor for possition 1,1 is in position 3,3.
On symbolab it calculates it correctly. Am i not using the correct function? What am i missing here?

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `Minors` does not what one usually expects. Please read the documentation of `Minors` more carefully, in particular the "Details" section.

Comment: The output is consistent with the documentation of [`Minors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html), see first point of Details. I agree it's not the definition I know either though.

Comment: You could always 'roll your own':  `Table[Det@Drop[mat, {i},{j}], {i,3},{j,3}]//MatrixForm`.  Also, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148382/106) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) might be of interest.

Comment: From the documentation, `Map[Reverse, Minors[mat], {0,1}]` may be what you are looking for? And: `Map[Reverse, Minors[mat], {0,1}]==Table[Det@Drop[mat, {i},{j}], {i,3},{j,3}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the more natural order by post-processing

```
(mat = {{a, b, c}, {l, m, n}, {x, y, z}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
min = Minors[mat];
(Reverse[min, {1, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]